# What should we do if we realise the Queen should have been on the board?

Tags: carrom

We forgot to return the Queen to the board after my opponent failed to cover it, and continued to play. What's the correct way to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

**Treat it as covered.**

According to [these rules](http://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm):

> 96) If the Queen is pocketed by a stroke and is not covered, the Queen shall be taken out for placing. If not noticed by the Umpire or by the opponent, before the next stroke is made, the Queen shall be recorded as properly covered.

In a casual setting, however, I'd take it out and place it before your next turn (so you get the next shot on it).

Comment: What is the source of these rules? Are they from a Carrom publisher or just something that some guy made up? The bright green website doesn't inspire a lot of confidence. He mentions some books, but I don't know anything about them.

Comment: They line up with these http://www.carrom.org/icf/?page=3&subcat=20 but that site seems to be broken on additional pages. I've seen the same rules in a few places previously, but it's been a while since I looked.around.